# How to show only one category from the start jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter, categories

I don't know a lot of jQuery, I only know CSS and HTML but I'm guessing that what I need to do is pretty simple.

I grabbed a code somewhere and modified it to make a category filter.
Here's an image of what I've done.

[image]

Everything works fine.
The only thing I want to do is: when it loads at first, show only a specific category... Not all.

Here's the original code I grabbed:
*(as mine has some spanish words and long svg paths which are not relevant)*

```js
(function($) {

  'use strict';

  var $filters = $('.filter [data-filter]'),
    $boxes = $('.boxes [data-category]');

  $filters.on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this);
    
    $filters.removeClass('active');
    $this.addClass('active');

    var $filterColor = $this.attr('data-filter');

    if ($filterColor == 'all') {
      $boxes.removeClass('is-animated')
        .fadeOut().finish().promise().done(function() {
          $boxes.each(function(i) {
            $(this).addClass('is-animated').delay((i++) * 200).fadeIn();
          });
        });
    } else {
      $boxes.removeClass('is-animated')
        .fadeOut().finish().promise().done(function() {
          $boxes.filter('[data-category = "' + $filterColor + '"]').each(function(i) {
            $(this).addClass('is-animated').delay((i++) * 200).fadeIn();
          });
        });
    }
  });

})(jQuery);
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  font: 18px/1.65 sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;    
  display: block;
  color: #333;
}

h2 {
  color: #333;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

.filter {
  margin: 30px 0 10px;
}

.filter a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 2px solid #333;
  position: relative;
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.boxes {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.boxes a {
  width: 23%;
  border: 2px solid #333;
  margin: 0 1% 20px 1%;
  line-height: 60px;
}

.all {
  background: khaki;
}

.green {
  background: lightgreen;
}

.blue {
  background: lightblue;
}

.red {
  background: lightcoral;
}

.filter a.active:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 15px 15px 0 0;
  border-color: #333 transparent transparent transparent;
}

.is-animated {
  animation: .6s zoom-in;
}

@keyframes zoom-in {
  0% {
   transform: scale(.1);
  } 
  100% {
    transform: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cta filter">
  <a class="green" data-filter="green" href="#" role="button">Show Green Boxes</a>
  <a class="blue" data-filter="blue" href="#" role="button">Show Blue Boxes</a>
  <a class="red" data-filter="red" href="#" role="button">Show Red Boxes</a>
</div>

<div class="boxes">
  <a class="red" data-category="red" href="#">Box1</a>
  <a class="green" data-category="green" href="#">Box2</a>
  <a class="blue" data-category="blue" href="#">Box3</a>
  <a class="green" data-category="green" href="#">Box4</a>
  <a class="red" data-category="red" href="#">Box5</a>
  <a class="green" data-category="green" href="#">Box6</a>
  <a class="blue" data-category="blue" href="#">Box7</a>
  <a class="red" data-category="red" href="#">Box8</a>
  <a class="green" data-category="green" href="#">Box9</a>
  <a class="blue" data-category="blue" href="#">Box10</a>
  <a class="red" data-category="red" href="#">Box11</a>
  <a class="green" data-category="green" href="#">Box12</a>
  <a class="blue" data-category="blue" href="#">Box13</a>
  <a class="green" data-category="green" href="#">Box14</a>
  <a class="red" data-category="red" href="#">Box15</a>
  <a class="blue" data-category="blue" href="#">Box16</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Show us your html code and tell us what you want to accomplish with it

Comment: I added the original code snippet so it's clearer what I wanted to do, when page first loads I want to show only the green boxes and not all categories... thanks!

Comment: Your question has all chances to be interpreted as: *«Please help me coding from what I copy/pasted... I don't really care to understand. It should only do what I want. I will tell you. You tell the code. Thanks free-coding for lazy people.»*

Comment: that's not the reason why I copied the original code in here, my code has spanish words in it so I didn't paste it because I don't want to confuse you and I have svg paths in my filter menu, so that will add a lot more code that's not relevant, I do care to understand and I looked up solutions to my problem but I found none online, that's why I came here for help 
the proof: http://imgur.com/Jm8GTKL

Comment: Well, I think you should edit your question with all these relevant infos. There a limit to be "minimal" as per [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and your question should also be "complete".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I only added two lines to your minimal demo.

```
// Onload Show green ones:
 $('a[class="green"]').click();
```

And it shows the green items onload.

```js
(function($) {

  'use strict';

  var $filters = $('.filter [data-filter]'),
    $boxes = $('.boxes [data-category]');

  $filters.on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this);
    
    $filters.removeClass('active');
    $this.addClass('active');

    var $filterColor = $this.attr('data-filter');

    if ($filterColor == 'all') {
      $boxes.removeClass('is-animated')
        .fadeOut().finish().promise().done(function() {
          $boxes.each(function(i) {
            $(this).addClass('is-animated').delay((i++) * 200).fadeIn();
          });
        });
    } else {
      $boxes.removeClass('is-animated')
        .fadeOut().finish().promise().done(function() {
          $boxes.filter('[data-category = "' + $filterColor + '"]').each(function(i) {
            $(this).addClass('is-animated').delay((i++) * 200).fadeIn();
          });
        });
    }
  });
  
  // Onload Show green ones:
  $('a[class="green"]').click();

})(jQuery);
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  font: 18px/1.65 sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;    
  display: block;
  color: #333;
}

h2 {
  color: #333;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

.filter {
  margin: 30px 0 10px;
}

.filter a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 2px solid #333;
  position: relative;
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.boxes {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.boxes a {
  width: 23%;
  border: 2px solid #333;
  margin: 0 1% 20px 1%;
  line-height: 60px;
}

.all {
  background: khaki;
}

.green {
  background: lightgreen;
}

.blue {
  background: lightblue;
}

.red {
  background: lightcoral;
}

.filter a.active:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 15px 15px 0 0;
  border-color: #333 transparent transparent transparent;
}

.is-animated {
  animation: .6s zoom-in;
}

@keyframes zoom-in {
  0% {
   transform: scale(.1);
  } 
  100% {
    transform: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cta filter">
  <a class="green" data-filter="green" href="#" role="button">Show Green Boxes</a>
  <a class="blue" data-filter="blue" href="#" role="button">Show Blue Boxes</a>
  <a class="red" data-filter="red" href="#" role="button">Show Red Boxes</a>
</div>

<div class="boxes">
  <a class="red" data-category="red" href="#">Box1</a>
  <a class="green" data-category="green" href="#">Box2</a>
  <a class="blue" data-category="blue" href="#">Box3</a>
  <a class="green" data-category="green" href="#">Box4</a>
  <a class="red" data-category="red" href="#">Box5</a>
  <a class="green" data-category="green" href="#">Box6</a>
  <a class="blue" data-category="blue" href="#">Box7</a>
  <a class="red" data-category="red" href="#">Box8</a>
  <a class="green" data-category="green" href="#">Box9</a>
  <a class="blue" data-category="blue" href="#">Box10</a>
  <a class="red" data-category="red" href="#">Box11</a>
  <a class="green" data-category="green" href="#">Box12</a>
  <a class="blue" data-category="blue" href="#">Box13</a>
  <a class="green" data-category="green" href="#">Box14</a>
  <a class="red" data-category="red" href="#">Box15</a>
  <a class="blue" data-category="blue" href="#">Box16</a>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried to use the function you gave me: $('a[class="especiales"]').click(); but it didn't worked, I used: 
// Onload Show especiales
$( ".especiales" ).click();
And it worked, I don't know if it's because I have more classes besides the "colors" on my "a classes", thanks very much for your help Patrice, I appreciate your time and guidance :)